# A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'MyController._config'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to get value from appsettings to MyController in .Net Core 3.1 MVC. Here I need to achieve this in below way:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private IConfiguration _config;

    public MyController(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public string apiURL = _config.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:MMServiceURL");
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "MMServiceURL": "http://localhost:57645/api/",
    }
}
```

But when I try to do so, I'm getting below error.

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'MyController._config'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8fVB.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your field to be a property instead, like this:

```
public string apiURL => _config.GetValue<string>("ServiceURL");
```

When using `=` you are creating a field.

When using `=>` you are creating a get-only property.